# Random date in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, random, date

I'm looking for some succinct, modern C# code to generate a random date between Jan 1 1995 and the current date.

I'm thinking some solution that utilizes Enumerable.Range somehow may make this more succinct.

Comment: Answer in [Random DateTime between range - not unified output](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14511053) has helper method with From/To date parameters

Answer (score 290, accepted):

```
private Random gen = new Random();
DateTime RandomDay()
{
    DateTime start = new DateTime(1995, 1, 1);
    int range = (DateTime.Today - start).Days;           
    return start.AddDays(gen.Next(range));
}
```

For better performance if this will be called repeatedly, create the `start` and `gen` (and maybe even `range`) variables *outside* of the function.

Comment: Random is only pseudo-random.  If you need truly random, try using RNGCryptoServiceProvider from the System.Security.Cryptography namespace.

Comment: Thanks tvanfosson. Pseudo-random is sufficient for this problem.

Comment: Actually, Random isn't even particularly pseudo-random unless you keep the instance around for a while and keep getting values out of it.

Comment: +1 for David's comment.  If you call the above method twice in quick succession then it's more than likely to return the same value.  The Random constructor above uses the current time as a seed, which is DateTime.Now.  That value only increments every 15 milliseconds. A field would be better.

Comment: Which is why this is only a sample, rather than production code.

Comment: Yep, that works for me; my real-world code will have the Random instance outside the method itself.

Comment: @Ronnie your edit caused compilation error (Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int') please don't change other people code and if you do that be extra careful and **check before you do that**. Thanks.

Comment: @ShadowWizard My bad. I was thinking that Days was not the most significant part of a TimeSpan, and so the difference between Days and TotalDays would be very pronounced, as it is with Minutes.

Comment: Does the result include today?

Comment: @SalmanA You can find out quickly by using yesterday instead of 1995 as the epoch. Looks like [the answer is "No".](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qd5B4i)

Comment: @Joel Just add 1 to range. OP is not clear if today must be included but you can always make the answer clear about the edge case.

Answer (score 30):

This is in slight response to Joel's comment about making a slighly more optimized version.  Instead of returning a random date directly, why not return a generator function which can be called repeatedly to create a random date.

```
Func<DateTime> RandomDayFunc()
{
    DateTime start = new DateTime(1995, 1, 1); 
    Random gen = new Random(); 
    int range = ((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Today - start)).Days; 
    return () => start.AddDays(gen.Next(range));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is beneficial? Couldn't start, gen, and range be class members instead?

Comment: They could and in this case they are.  Under the hood this will generate a lexical closure which is a clrass containing start,gen and range as members.  This is just more concise.

Comment: Nice function, I'm just hoping that nobody is going to use it as: `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { array[i].DateProp = RandomDayFunc()(); }`

Comment: How is this function used, can someone please explain? I mean how can I call it?

Comment: @BurakKarakuş: You get a factory first: `var getRandomDate = RandomDayFunc();` then you call it to get random dates: `var randomDate = getRandomDate();` Mind that you need to reuse getRandomDate in order for this to be more useful than Joel's answer.

Answer (score 15):

I have taken @Joel Coehoorn answer and made the changes he adviced - put the variable out of the method and put all in class. Plus now the time is random too. Here is the result.

```
class RandomDateTime
{
    DateTime start;
    Random gen;
    int range;

    public RandomDateTime()
    {
        start = new DateTime(1995, 1, 1);
        gen = new Random();
        range = (DateTime.Today - start).Days;
    }

    public DateTime Next()
    {
        return start.AddDays(gen.Next(range)).AddHours(gen.Next(0,24)).AddMinutes(gen.Next(0,60)).AddSeconds(gen.Next(0,60));
    }
}
```

And example how to use to write 100 random DateTimes to console:

```
RandomDateTime date = new RandomDateTime();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(date.Next());
}
```

Comment: Why do you create Random() twice?  Once in class variable gen declaration and other time in the c-tor?

Comment: Yeah, once is enough. I fixed it.

Comment: It's about four times faster to generate just a single random number of seconds and add that to your start date: `range = (int)(DateTime.Today - start).TotalSeconds;` and `return start.AddSeconds(gen.Next(range));`.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you gonna present alternate optimization, we can also go for an iterator:

```
 static IEnumerable<DateTime> RandomDay()
 {
    DateTime start = new DateTime(1995, 1, 1);
    Random gen = new Random();
    int range = ((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Today - start)).Days;
    while (true)
        yield return  start.AddDays(gen.Next(range));        
}
```

you could use it like this:

```
int i=0;
foreach(DateTime dt in RandomDay())
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
    if (++i == 10)
        break;
}
```

Comment: One thing to consider between an iterator vs. a generator function is that the iterator solution will produce an IDisposable value.  This forces the caller to dispose or pay the price of having a finalizer live in the GC.  The generator needs no disposing

Comment: @JaredPar, that's not quite right.  Just because a type implements IDisposable does not mean it is finalizable.

Answer (score 3):

Start with a fixed date object (Jan 1, 1995), and add a random number of days with AddDays (obviusly, pay attention not surpassing the current date).

Comment: Thanks Friol. I was gonna ask how to limit the number passed into random. Joel has posted an example with code sample, so I'll mark his response as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
DateTime datetoday = DateTime.Now;

int rndYear = rnd.Next(1995, datetoday.Year);
int rndMonth = rnd.Next(1, 12);
int rndDay = rnd.Next(1, 31);

DateTime generateDate = new DateTime(rndYear, rndMonth, rndDay);
Console.WriteLine(generateDate);
```

//this maybe is not the best method but is fast and easy to understand

Comment: This may generate an invalid DateTime, such as February 30th

Answer (score 1):

One more solution to the problem, this time a class to which you provide a range you want the dates in. Its down to random minutes in the results.

```
/// <summary>
/// A random date/time class that provides random dates within a given range
/// </summary>
public class RandomDateTime
{
    private readonly Random rng = new Random();
    private readonly int totalMinutes;
    private readonly DateTime startDateTime;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RandomDateTime"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startDate">The start date.</param>
    /// <param name="endDate">The end date.</param>
    public RandomDateTime(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        this.startDateTime = startDate;
        TimeSpan timeSpan = endDate - startDate;
        this.totalMinutes = (int)timeSpan.TotalMinutes;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the next random datetime object within the range of startDate and endDate provided in the ctor
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A DateTime.</returns>
    public DateTime NextDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            TimeSpan newSpan = new TimeSpan(0, rng.Next(0, this.totalMinutes), 0);
            return this.startDateTime + newSpan;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this to spit out 5 random dates between january 1st 2020 and december 31 2022:

```
RandomDateTime rdt = new RandomDateTime(DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020"), DateTime.Parse("31/12/2022"));

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    Debug.WriteLine(rdt.NextDateTime);
```

Comment: One might add features like granularity, randomization of only time/ onkly date part, only certain weekdays, etc

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is actualy an `ulong` under the hood. With some of it bits reserved to datetime's kind. So you can do it like this.

```cs
public static DateTime NextDateTime(this Random random, DateTime? minValue = null, DateTime? maxValue = null)
{
    var lowerBound = (minValue ?? DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(2)).Ticks;
    var upperBound = (maxValue ?? DateTime.MaxValue.AddDays(-2)).Ticks;

    return new DateTime(random.NextInt64(lowerBound, upperBound));
}
```

MinValue/MaxValue has a terrible habbit to fail during ToLocal/ToUniversal time calls. Hense `AddDays` to exclude edge cases.

Now you can use this method to get required date with

```cs
new Random().NextDateTime(new DateTime(1995, 1, 1), DateTime.UtcNow)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late in to the game, but here is one solution which works fine:

```
    void Main()
    {
        var dateResult = GetRandomDates(new DateTime(1995, 1, 1), DateTime.UtcNow, 100);
        foreach (var r in dateResult)
            Console.WriteLine(r);
    }

    public static IList<DateTime> GetRandomDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime maxDate, int range)
    {
        var randomResult = GetRandomNumbers(range).ToArray();

        var calculationValue = maxDate.Subtract(startDate).TotalMinutes / int.MaxValue;
        var dateResults = randomResult.Select(s => startDate.AddMinutes(s * calculationValue)).ToList();
        return dateResults;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> GetRandomNumbers(int size)
    {
        var data = new byte[4];
        using (var rng = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider(data))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                rng.GetBytes(data);

                var value = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
                yield return value < 0 ? value * -1 : value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Small method that returns a random date as string, based on some simple input parameters. Built based on variations from the above answers:

```
public string RandomDate(int startYear = 1960, string outputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd")
{
   DateTime start = new DateTime(startYear, 1, 1);
   Random gen = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
   int range = (DateTime.Today - start).Days;
   return start.AddDays(gen.Next(range)).ToString(outputDateFormat);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Useful extension based of @Jeremy Thompson's solution

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static DateTime Next(this Random random, DateTime start, DateTime? end = null)
    {
        end ??= new DateTime();
        int range = (end.Value - start).Days;
        return start.AddDays(random.Next(range));
    }
}
```

Comment: The `new DateTime()` is `01/01/0001 00:00:00`. Are you sure about that?