# DateTime In C# + Compare Datetime

Tags: c#

1. I need format type DateTime into: "dd/mm/yyyy".
2. I want to add, sub, compare between 2 DateTime.
            ex: 23/12/1991 > 2/1/1990.
                 23/12/1991 - 20(days) = 3/12/1991
   Could you help me, please.! Thank very much.! ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get that format use:

```
yourDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy);
```

To add to a date:

```
yourDate.AddDays(15);
yourDate.AddMonths(3);
```

and so on

To subtract from a date

```
yourDate.AddDays(-12);
yourDate.AddMonths(-3);
```

and so on

And any date objects can be compared with the normal `> < <= >=` operators.

Comment: I need get random DateTime between 2 Days. ex: between 1/2/2003 and 2/3/2003??? Thank for help me.!

Comment: @VõHoàiLên - to get a random date, have a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194863/random-date-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Format:

```
dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Add and Sub: Look at the different overload of DateTime.Add and the various others (AddDays, AddHours, etc).

Compare:

```
dateTime1 - dateTime2
```

That will return a Timespan. You can thus do:

```
(dateTime1-dateTime2).Days >= 20
```

Answer (score 0):

To format the string representation if you can do the following:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
var dateString = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

In order the add/sub days to a DateTime object, use the `AddDays()` method:

```
// Subtract 20 days
var date = DateTime.Now;
var twentyDaysAgo = date.AddDays(-20);
```

There is also an `AddMonths()` method that works in the same way.