# Random DateTime between range - not unified output

Tags: c#, datetime, random, timespan

I implemented the below RandomDate, but I always keep getting values closed to "From" date, i probably miss something here....

```
public static DateTime GetRandomDate(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        var range = new TimeSpan(to.Ticks - from.Ticks);

        var rnd = new Random();

        var randTimeSpan = new TimeSpan((long)(range.TotalSeconds - rnd.Next(0, (int)range.TotalSeconds))); 

        return from + randTimeSpan;
    }
```

Comment: While not the (only) reason for your error, the `var rnd = new Random()` line will cause headaches if you intend to call this method frequently.

Comment: see this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could change to:

```
static readonly Random rnd = new Random();
public static DateTime GetRandomDate(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    var range = to - from;

    var randTimeSpan = new TimeSpan((long)(rnd.NextDouble() * range.Ticks)); 

    return from + randTimeSpan;
}
```

Explanation: I used `NextDouble()` because it gives a number between `0.0` and `1.0`. Your return value won't be a whole number of seconds in my solution. And I moved `rnd` out to a field on the class/struct. Because it's best to reuse one `Random` instance, and not create a new one every time one needs just one additional random number.

Comment: took this idea, thanks. I also had the Random Member as a ThreadLocal<Random> like Alexx suggested

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that:

```
var randTimeSpan = new TimeSpan((long)(range.TotalSeconds - rnd.Next(0, (int)range.TotalSeconds)));
```

is creating a TimeSpan from TICKS, not from SECONDS.

You need:

```
var randTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((long)(range.TotalSeconds - rnd.Next(0, (int)range.TotalSeconds)));
```

(Please check the cast too - it needs to be a double passed to FromSeconds)

Comment: The random should also either be a field in the class or an argument in this method, otherwise it's always created with the same seed when this method is called very fast(f.e. in a loop).

Comment: This can causes ArgumentOutOfRangeException when range.TotalSeconds is greater Int32.MaxValue

Comment: @user1320170 Indeed, it will only work up to around 68 years range; however, it seems that this is enough for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

This is because [`TimeSpan`'s constructor that takes a `long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz841zbz.aspx) expects ticks, not seconds.

```
var randTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(range.Ticks - rnd.Next(0, range.Ticks));
```

Comment: `rnd.Next()` doesn't take long as an argument, only int

Answer (score 0):

Fixed ArgumentOutOfRangeException:

```
public static DateTime GetRandomDateTime(DateTime? min = null, DateTime? max = null)
{
    min = min ?? new DateTime(1753, 01, 01);
    max = max ?? new DateTime(9999, 12, 31);

    var range = max.Value - min.Value;
    var randomUpperBound = (Int32) range.TotalSeconds;
    if (randomUpperBound <= 0)
        randomUpperBound = Rnd.Next(1, Int32.MaxValue);

    var randTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((Int64) (range.TotalSeconds - Rnd.Next(0, randomUpperBound)));
    return min.Value.Add(randTimeSpan);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is we just need some random number of ticks added to start datetime to get a random date in between start and end. So my solution does not create any `TimeSpan` objects.

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random ();
private static readonly object syncLock = new object ();

public static DateTime RandomDate(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    lock ( syncLock )
    {
         return from.AddTicks ((long) ( random.NextDouble () * ( to.Ticks - from.Ticks ) ));
    }
 }
```