# Generating random DateTime between a given DateTime range - C#

Tags: c#

I have a listener which needs to be active randomly for 10 time for say 20 min in a given time period. So if the time period is say from 2013/08/20 10:00 to 2013/08/20 22:00, I need to generate a random DateTime 10 times between this range keeping in mind that the listener needs a time of 20 min.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I understand your requirement. What have you come up with so far ?

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random DateTime between range](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14511053/342740)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Ticks` property on `DateTime` to find the difference between the two and then generate a random number of ticks in that range:

```
Random r = new Random();
int randTicks = r.Next(0, (int) (dt2.Ticks - dt1.Ticks));
```

Now you can add that random # of ticks to make a random `DateTime` between `dt1` and `dt2`:

```
DateTime dtRand = dt1.AddTicks(randTicks);
```

Comment: Simple and effective, you may need to convert the difference of two ticks to an int first though, as Next method doesn't take long type.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work as i test it, casting long to int directly will cause overflow.

Comment: @liang I suppose if the difference between the dates is large enough this would be the case. If so, I'd recommend a more robust solution which individually randomizes each element of a DateTime based on what kind of precision you need (just a date, or both a date and time, etc). The solution provided below by Karl may also work for you though that only works down to the minute and doesn't randomize the time any further.

Comment: i still prefer the simpleness of your approach, a further precision scale down may do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = endDate - startDate;
var randomTest = new Random();

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TimeSpan newSpan = new TimeSpan(0, randomTest.Next(0, (int)timeSpan.TotalMinutes), 0);
    DateTime newDate = startDate + newSpan;

    // Do something with newDate before you loop again
}
```

Note: You will need to provide the `endDate` and `startDate` values.