# Getting random numbers with two digits despite being less than 10

Tags: c#, random

I want my program to randomly select a date to serve as a birth date. The first randomized number is the year, the second is the month and the last one is the day.

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < antal; i++)
    array[i].Number = rand.Next(00, 99) +
                      rand.Next(01, 12) +
                      rand.Next(01, 30);
```

However if the randomized number turns out to be less than 10, say 3, I want it to show "03", not merely "3". Is there any way to do this in C#? Or is there a better way to randomize birth dates?

Comment: I'm guessing `array[i].Number` is a string.

Comment: If you want to create random `DateTime`s, why don't you just create random `DateTime`s instead of random years, months and days? Something like `randomDate = startDate.AddDays(rand.Next((endDate - startDate).Days))`. Then you can `ToString()` the date any way you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random date in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194863/random-date-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numbers don't have formats - an integer is an integer, so the number three can be equally represented as 03, 3, 0x3 etc.

Additionally, you're simply *adding* numbers - you're not concatenating string representations. So the first number might be 50, the second might be 6, and the third might be 3... so you end up with 59, not 500603 which is presumably what you expected.

You *could* simply multiply by 10000 for the year and 100 for the month, but surely it would be better to store a `DateTime` value instead.

The simplest way to get a random date between (say) 1950 and 2050 exclusive would be:

```
int year = random.Next(100) + 1950;
int daysInYear = DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) ? 366 : 365;
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(random.Next(daysInYear));
```

This way you can get *all* the right days of the year, with no invalid ones - in your original code you could easily have ended up with February 30th, for example... assuming you'd actually fixed your code to take account of the fact that the second argument to `Random.Next` is *exclusive* rather than *inclusive*. (Otherwise you'd never get the 30th, and you'd also never get a value in December...)

It's important to use the most appropriate data type whenever possible. If you want to represent a date, use a date-related type. If you want to represent text, use a string. If you want to represent a number, use the appropriate numeric type. You'll find that if you use the right data type, you can get rid of a *lot* of errors.

Comment: What if `Number` was a `string`?

Comment: @Nick: Then a) it's badly named; b) I'd question whether it's an appropriate type to represent a date; c) you can easily format a `DateTime` to a string in whatever format you want, but I'd *start* with a value of the right data type.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It is indeed badly named, and to be perfectly honest I was not aware that there existed a DateTime method to do this. I'm still very new to this, but I'm trying to learn. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

```
string.Format("{0:00}",1); //Prints 01
string.Format("{0:00}",2); //Prints 02
```

Comment: That's true, but the OP's code is still fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
rnd.Next(0, 99).ToString("D2");
```

this will make sure that numbers are minimal 2 digit in string representation of the number.

```
array[i].Number = rand.Next(00, 99)ToString("D2") +
                  rand.Next(01, 12)ToString("D2") +
                  rand.Next(01, 30)ToString("D2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the integers to a string and send the formation with.

```
int Number = 3;

String NumberInString = Number.ToString("00"); //Will return 03
```

Comment: I'm sorry, you are correct, the variable initilisation was in VB, but I was confiused because the last answer I made in VB. Also, I know, that he want the code in C#, because I used semicolon....
Is this really a reason for downvote ?
You could indicate this, instead of instantly vote down...

Comment: I can always vote up when corrected. I do not assume someone will reply on my comments. I am not gonna check every day if everybody reacted so I simply downvote with a comment (I think that is honest), and I can always restore it.

Comment: Yes, normaly I would say its correct to downvote, but you can really saw, that it was a mistake from my side. Even the comment is C#
Can you please undo the downvote, I updated the code ;)

Comment: I already correct it. I was looking at the version where your `int` was with a capitle `I`.

Answer (score 0):

A number has no idea of a format. You can format a string.

You could use [`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) if you have already a string:

```
string day = "1"; 
day = day.PadLeft(2, '0');
```

If `day` is numeric:

```
int day = 1;
string dayStr = day.ToString("D2");
```

[Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/2LUxeE)

Comment: -1: PadLeft does only work with strings, not with numbers. Where is your "day" coming from?

Comment: @MartinMulder: `PadLeft` works with strings, yes. Please read again my answer. To make it clearer i have added the declaration of `day` (altough i've already mentioned that it's a string).

Answer (score 0):

You can format your numbers like this:

```
n.ToString("00");
```

In your case (assuming your `Number` is a number):

```
array[i].Number.ToString("00")
```

or, if `Number` is a string:

```
array[i].Number = rand.Next(00, 99).ToString("00") +
                  rand.Next(01, 12).ToString("00") +
                  rand.Next(01, 30).ToString("00");
```

With your whole date solution (assuming your `Number` is a number):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00}-{1:00}-{2:00}", array[0].Number, array[1].Number, array[2].Number);
```

Answer (score 0):

you get the random number as a single digit, but when you print it, you print it prepended by 0. The pre fix 0 can be made for strings, but no language compiler will help you store "05" instead of "5" in an int variable!

Answer (score 0):

Create at first your random date between today and 1/1/1900

```
    DateTime start = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
    Random gen = new Random();

    int range = (DateTime.Today - start).TotalDays;           
    var myRandomDate = start.AddDays(gen.Next(range));
```

Then format the date to achieve the "0 pad" for day less than 10.

```
    myRandomDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```