# How to generate random numbers in timestamp format

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

In my test I have to fill the application number for that I already have guid method to generate random numbers because for each time while running the test it should generate different numbers.

```
var DocumentNo = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
editCasePage.FillDocumentNumber(DocumentNo);
```

but I need document number in time stamp format.How can i do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clarify what you want. Are you saying you want the document number to be an ISO8601 timestamp? Would `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")` not suffice?

Comment: @Mutu Arron a random number will give you, ex. 10, so this number will represent what, your question is unclear

Comment: Please provide an example of your input and what your expected output.

Comment: 1. `DocumentNo` is already a string. No point of calling it's `ToString()` method. 2. What is a *time stamp format*? You can simply generate a random number (using in instance of the `Random` class) and add it to `DateTime.Now` and then use `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: If you already have a Guid, why not just use it instead of messing with some other format?

Comment: @john Exactly what i am looking for i need an alternative option for guid.

Comment: I can´t imagine how a guid like `"F9168C5E-CEB2-4faa-B6BF-329BF39FA1E4"` should be transofmred to a timestamp or a date at all.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Take a look at my answer. ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random date in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194863/random-date-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a random date then create one. One simple solution would be:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            var bytes = guid.ToByteArray();
            var rawValue = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
            var inRangeValue = Math.Abs(rawValue) % DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks;
            var date = new DateTime(inRangeValue);

            Console.WriteLine(date);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this method does not guarantee unique results in any way. using a GUID [practically guarantees uniqueness.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid) (though not completely guarantees it).

Comment: A guid has 128 bit and a datetime has 64 bit. So you always have duplicates when you try to convert guids to datetimes.

Comment: While your comment is correct, I didn't say *convert guids to datetimes.* I only pointed out the fact that `Guid.NewGuid()` would return a unique value, while `random.Next` does not guarantee it in any way.

Comment: That's right. Just to get more uniqueness, I changed my answer to convert a guid (partially) into a DateTime. ;-)